# where to set data in iOS app

Tags: database, sqlite, xcode6

I have an iOS app and I want to change data but I don't know where ..
In the app I find `quote.sqlite` and `quote2.sqlite3` and data in `database.m`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not insert data in Xcode through the UI. You have to either insert it through Core Data or use an external SQLite Editor, there are some on the App Store, even for free.  I'm happy with "SQLPro for SQLite".

If you did not yet create a Data Model, do so by going to `File` -> `New` -> `File...` -> `iOS` -> `Core Data` -> `Data Model`.